# WebApp hosting set of Oauth API calls and controlling access

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am planning on creating a single war file (webapp) that will host various API calls to different back end systems. I will be using OAuth2 to control access via client_credentials grant. I plan on issuing clientId/secrets to various application owners to control the application access to my secured APIs.

1. Is it possible to configure my spring security configuration to
   only allow certain clientId's to access specific API's and block
   them from using others? 
   For example, client123 has access to call GET from apiA but cannot call PUT to apiB.
2. I thought about using scopes but it seems
   my CAS OAuth server may not support scopes for client_credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Spring Security supports a number of modes, though you are correct that scopes are the preferred method.

What I'd probably recommend is that you still use scopes on the Spring Security side, even if that representation only lives in your APIs, so that way as CAS matures, or if you otherwise are able to change over to scopes in the future, the Resource Servers will stay the same.

So, let's say that you have a Spring Security OAuth 2.0 Resource Server that uses JWTs:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt();
}
```

The hook to convert the `Jwt` into a `Collection` of `GrantedAuthority`s is `Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>>`. Your implementation might look something like:

```
public class ByClientIdJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter
    implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        // manually infer scopes from client ids
        String clientId = jwt.getSubject();
        if ("abc".equals(clientId)) {
            return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCOPE_read"));
        }
        // ... etc.
    }
}
```

And then you can wire it with:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new ByClientIdJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter());
    http
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(converter);
}
```

I'm making a couple of assumptions, including how the client can be derived from the token, but the general idea is there.

Spring Security 5.2 GAs in a couple of weeks and will support opaque tokens, in case OAuth2 CAS doesn't support JWTs. In that case, you'd do something similar, just with the `opaqueToken()` DSL instead.

Thereafter, you can configure Spring Security by path in the same way as other authentication mechanisms:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/apiA/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_apiA")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/apiB/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_apiB:read")
            .and()
       .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(...);
}
```